# Failure modes of old motherboards vs new motherboards

Tags: component-failure

I have a question regarding the difference in common failure modes between an older motherboard such as the ABIT BP6, and a new motherboard such as what you might find in an Intel NUC. What is a failure mode you might have with the former and not with the latter?
My guess is capacitors just because of the different cap designs between the two, or perhaps expandability?
Thanks!

Comment: I suspect those that voted to close this question didn't see any clear connection between expandability and component failure. Also they might have thought this question is a bit out of scope, since the ABIT BP6 was sold from 1999 which is considered a bit late to fit in this place by some.

Comment: Maybe if it had been phrased more as a question about the old hardware. (ie. what failure modes old hardware had that have now been more or less eliminated, and what failure modes we take for granted now which would surprise people used to old hardware... sort of like how how the CodeWarrior docs instructed people to make regular backups of their distribution floppies, but you're unlikely to see that for something distributed on CD-ROM.)

Comment: I think still capacitors are the main cause. Second cause is short circuit or an open circuit due to wire corrosion, electrical overload or chemical effect.

Comment: Thanks @peterh-ReinstateMonica for your answer and thanks everyone for your comments